# Make the JDBC call throw a SQLException for a test case

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, jdbc

I am writing test cases for my program and to maximize the code coverage I have to raise a SQLException, that exception will then be checked in my test case.

```
public double getTotalAmount(String form,String name) {
    DbManager manager = new DbManager();
    double amount = 0;
    ResultSet executeQuery = manager.findAll("select amount From "+form+" where employee_name='"+name+"'");
    try {
        while (executeQuery.next()) {
            String tempAmount = executeQuery.getString("amount");
            amount += Double.valueOf(tempAmount);
        }
        return amount;
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    manager.closeConnection();
    return -1;
```

Now I am unable to raise the SQLException in my code, can you suggest me how can I raise this exception in my code.

Comment: You will need to mock your database layer, so you'll want to inject your db manager. Also you should read up on separation of concerns and wrap you database code in a Repository class, that will make it easier to mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the javadocs

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)

> SQLException - if the columnIndex is not valid;

so in your code do

```
String tempAmount = executeQuery.getString(1000);
```

If your `tester` class needs to catch this exception, then you will also need to throw it from `getTotalAmount`